# htaccess - Load css, js, images

Tags: .htaccess

I write htaccess with code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /MVC_PHP_Basic

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?link=$1&action=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?link=$1&id=$2&action=$3 [L]
```

And it works and My css,js, image is loaded with url localhost/users but is not load with url localhost/users/detail.

Errors: can't load file css,js.

I know this error is due to path of css,js file because i use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
```

When url is "localhost/users", href is "localhost/assets/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" (right).
And when url is "localhost/users/detail", href is "localhost/users/assets/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" (wrong).

Please tell me how to fix (I don't want to use "absolute path").

Answer (score 0):

Try to put / like this "/assets/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" and place your asset folder on the root folder, or you will have to use like this "/users/assets/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css"

Comment: It works with root url is "localhost", not works with root url is "localhost/myfolder" and htaccess file is created in my folder.